# How to plot treatment means per day with error bars and p values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, errorbar, ggpubr

So I have data that were collected on Day 0, Day 15, and at the end of experiment (WEAN). These are weights of the animals between two treatments. It goes something like this:

```
PIG TRT DAY0 DAY15 WEAN 
1 SOY 1.48  5.22  8.35    
2 SOY 1.44  5.07  7.76   
3 SOY 1.66  5.30  9.46    
4 LIN 1.94  5.91 10.10   
5 LIN 1.54  4.96  9.01 
6 LIN 1.68  5.56  9.52
```

It composes of 61 pigs in total. With ggplot2 or ggpubr, how can I perform the statistics and plot the treatment means with x = day of weight collection and y = weights in a single line plot, with error bars and p-value?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Because I am shifting the analysis from SAS to R Studio. But now, I have the means, standard error of means, and the p-value. I was thinking if I can do the same analysis with R, then plot them using ggplot or ggpubr. But I do not know how to manipulate this data and plot them in different timepoints. 
I tried this, but this is only for one timepoint, I am not sure how to combine them.
```ggplot(df2, aes(x=time, y=pigletweightkg, group=treatment)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=treatment, color=treatment))+
  geom_point(aes(color=treatment))+
  theme(legend.position="right")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your sample data, I think that your purpose is to plot mean of each pigs per treatment and date. You may try

```
library(tidyverse)

dummy %>%
  select(-PIG) %>%
  melt() %>%
  group_by(TRT, variable) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value),
            sd = sd(value),
            upper = mean + 1.96 * sd,
            lower = mean - 1.96 * sd) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  ggplot(aes(variable, mean, color = TRT, group = TRT)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, width = 0.2), position = ) +
  xlab("date") + ylab("mean of pig's weights")
```

[image]